# Android Resources$NotFoundException When Evaluating Expression - Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-resources

I'm trying to evaluate an expression using the latest version of AS that looks this:

```
String.format(getString(R.string.xpto_1), getString(R.string.xpto_2))
```

I'm calling this from the "oncreate" method of an "Activity.kt", the result is 100% ok but I cannot evaluate the expression, always getting the exception mentioned in the title of this post.

How it's possible get the result but not when evaluating?

Can you evaluate an expression like that from the same point without exception?

Cheers

[image]

Comment: Yes, it looks like this:     
`<string name="xpto_1">Select categories:&#160;%s</string>`

There is no stack trace because this just happens when I'm trying to evaluate the expression, as I've mentioned the result is 100% when running the app.

Comment: I mean, the result of this: 
`String.format(getString(R.string.xpto_1), getString(R.string.xpto_2))`
is 100% (as expected), but when I'm trying to evaluate the same expression the exception happens.. Can you evaluate an expression like that from the same point without exception?

Comment: Can you share a project with that setup in e.g. github?

Comment: Nor sorry man, it's a private project but you can create a new one from the scratch and see if it works.. for me this kind of evaluation never worked, I can see just the result in the app, probably it's a very good bug in the IDE...

Comment: I tried this and I am able to evaluate without any problem. I think it can be a bug with your android studio's version.

Comment: Can you show your `R` class import line?

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot, what you should try is assigning the `getString($variable)`s to a variable then you can evaluate those two variables, because I feel, the evaluate is unable to actually access these resources, hence the exception